# double backslash replacing in python 3

Tags: python, escaping, backslash, repr

I'm trying to write Latex code in a txt file, and I need the formula to have a single backslash.

**Edit:**
Basically what im trying to do is taking from file1.txt some Latex code, replacing some of that code with words that contain single backslashes, and rewriting it to file2.txt:

`descr = dicc[key]['description']                                                         str_descr = repr(descr)
aux_descr = str_descr[1:len(str_descr)-1]
str = line.replace('****',aux_descr)
file2.write(str + '\n')`

Now suppose file1.txt has the next few lines of Latex code:

```
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\uncover<1-> {$****$}\\ \vspace{5pt}
\end{column}
```

AndI would like to replace '****' with str = rect\'angulo (\' is needed to write the accent mark so it shows up as rectángulo), so after I run the code I would like to have:

```
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\uncover<1-> {$rect\'angulo$}\\ \vspace{5pt}
\end{column}
```

but instead I get sothing like this:

```
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\uncover<1-> {$rect\\'angulo$}\\ \vspace{5pt}
\end{column}
```

with the double backslash on it.
Any suggestions?
**note:**
I added the first two lines of code, where I used `repr(descr)`, someone suggested it may be part of the problem.

Comment: Strings can be encoded, bytes can be decoded.

Comment: You may want to show the actual code that causes the incorrect output.

Comment: Keep in mind that on printed output, a double backslash is often a representation of a single backslash.

Comment: I suspect the error has to do with where you're getting the `aux_descr` from. You show some code slicing `str_descr`, which I'm guessing is stripping off quotation marks from the `repr` of a Python string. That's not a good way to go. You should fix the source of those strings so that they're not `repr`s of the values you actually want.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using repr in this way: str_descr = repr(descr). contextualizing, I'm taking descr from a dataFrame (excel sheet) using pandas. idk why the type of variable descr = dic[key][column1] is a float, but I figured out that repr(descr) returned a string. what should I do?

Comment: Why are you calling `repr`?

Comment: because ( and I don't know why) type(descr) is a float. and it's supposed to be a string because that's what Im storing in that cell of the dataframe.